# How to realize an UiTableWiev with placeholders?

Tags: uitableview, ios4, placeholder

How can i realize an UiTableWiev like this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QVb4.jpg

I appreciate everyone who gives me a tutorial.

Also a table like fb would be fine
http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/4162/photocr.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a UITextField to your UITableViewCell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    /* your standard UITableView setup code */

    UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(60, 12.7, 250, 20)];
    /* any other textField code you want to add */
    [cell addSubview: customTextField];

    return cell;
}
```

At the bottom of [the list](http://www.aboutobjects.com/tutorials.html), you will find **TableView with File-Based Persistence** which demonstrates how to do this.